# Getting null pointer exception while mapping the jooq record into an object

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jooq

I have a couple of JOOQ repositories which fetch the data from the Postgres DB and provides the data as value objects. I was using JOOQ 3.10.7 and everything working fine. I have upgraded my spring-boot version to 2.1.4 from 2.0.3 which upgraded the JOOQ version to 3.11.10. I started getting the NullPointerException while mapping the Jooq record.

```
    try {
       record = jooq.build()
            .select(user.name)
            .where(user.id.eq(1))
            .fetchSingle();
    } catch (NoDataFoundException e) {
      return null;
    }
    return record.into(String.class);
```

In the above scenario, the fetchSingle has to throw NoDataFoundException when there is no record to which matches the given criteria(user.id.eq(1)). But as per my observation, this is not throwing an exception but returning a record object which has fields as (user.name) and value as "null". Is this something expected? I tried using `fetchOne().into(String.class)` but the same issue persist.

Here is my JOOQ configuration class.

```
public class JooQJdbcImpl implements Jooq {

private final Settings defaultSettings = new Settings()
    .withRenderNameStyle(RenderNameStyle.AS_IS);

private final RecordMapperProvider recordMapperProvider = new DefaultRecordMapperProvider();

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Override
public DSLContext build() {
    return withSettings(defaultSettings);
}

@Override
public DSLContext withSettings(Settings settings) {
    final Configuration configuration = new DefaultConfiguration()
        .set(SQLDialect.POSTGRES_9_5)
        .set(dataSource)
        .set(recordMapperProvider)
        .set(settings);
    return DSL.using(configuration);
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you specifying the `RecordMapperProvider`?

Comment: ```private final RecordMapperProvider recordMapperProvider = new DefaultRecordMapperProvider();```

Providing the default record mapper provider is the issue. If we don't specify any, the configuration is taking the default record mapper provider. I hope something has changed in the ```DefaultConfiguration``` class with respect to RecordMapper in the recent release which breaks my code

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I follow. Can you be specific? Is there a specific bug in your example? If so, would you mind reporting it here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new

Answer (score 1):

In general, you could use [`fetchOneInto(String.class)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchOneInto-java.lang.Class-), which prevents the NPE when no record is found.

> But as per my observation, this is not throwing an exception but returning a record object which has fields as (user.name) and value as "null". Is this something expected?

Yes, that's expected. When you call `into(String.class)`, this will try to find the most appropriate `String` constructor and call it with the string argument, in this case, you're effectively calling `new String(null)`, which is not possible.

You don't have to rely on this behaviour, though. Just call:

```
return jooq.build()
        .select(user.name)
        .where(user.id.eq(1))
        .fetchOne(user.name);
```

Comment: Thanks @Lukas-eder. But still I have a doubt that why the JOOQ Record which is the result of the query execution is not null when there is no matching records in the database. It was mentioned in the documentation that ```fetchOne()``` will return null when there is no matching record

Comment: One more observation. Even when there are records in the database which match the given criteria, the resulting record object contains null values for the selected fields which throwing NPE when mapping that record into the respective value object. Anybody facing the similar issue?

Comment: @NageswaraRaOMaridu: That's unlikely if there really was no record. Are you sure about that?

Comment: Yes @Lukas Eder. I am facing that strange issue

Comment: @NageswaraRaOMaridu: Well, may I invite you to report an issue at https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new? Please include an MCVE if possible. This will probably depend on some edge case that is not easy to reproduce: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ-mcve